# Output Table in Hbase empty

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to read data from one table, do some processing and put the results in another table. The code for this is

```
'package examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;


public class HbaseCombinerExample {

    public static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<Text, FloatWritable> {

        private Text text = new Text();

        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int[] siteArray = {1, 8, 18, 22, 26, 35, 48, 51, 53, 81, 108, 110, 139, 146, 150, 154, 169, 181, 235, 240, 404, 405, 406, 407, 409, 410, 411, 671, 673, 695, 697, 698, 1001};

            String siteId = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("location"), Bytes.toBytes("site")));
            String param = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("param_name")));
            boolean bool = Arrays.asList(siteArray).contains(Integer.parseInt(siteId));

            if(bool && param.equals("o3")) {

                String year = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("date"), Bytes.toBytes("year")));
                String month = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("date"), Bytes.toBytes("month")));



String day = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("date"), Bytes.toBytes("day")));
                String hour = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("date"), Bytes.toBytes("hour")));
                String pollution = new String(value.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("value")));

                String val = year+month+day+hour+siteId;
                FloatWritable pollValue = new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat(pollution));

                text.set(val); // we can only emit Writables...

                context.write(text, pollValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyTableReducer extends TableReducer<Text, FloatWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            float i = 0;
            float count = 0;
           // ImmutableBytesWritable HKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()));

            for (FloatWritable val : values) {
                i += val.get();
             //   ++count;
            }

           // float avgPollution = i/count;
            Put HPut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()));
            HPut.add(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("avgPollutionValue"),Bytes.toBytes(i));

            context.write(null, HPut);
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            Job job = new Job(config, "HourlyAvg");
            job.setJarByClass(HbaseCombinerExample.class);

            String sourceTable = "airqualitys1";
            String targetTable = "bigd26-hbase-avg";
            Scan scan = new Scan();
            scan.setCaching(300); // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
            scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(sourceTable,scan, MyMapper.class,Text.class, FloatWritable.class, job);
            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(targetTable, MyTableReducer.class, job);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);

            if (!b) {
                      throw new IOException("error with job!");
            }
     }

}'
```

The problem is the there are no records in the output table. I am also getting this line when the map reduce runs.

'Task Id : attempt_1397249742212_1380_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED'  and 
 'Not able to initialize app-log directories in any of the configured local directories for app application_1397249742212_1407'

any information/suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Does any one have a slightest idea why is this happening?

Comment: OKay. Atleast can anyone tell this that if I want to scan the rows based on a column value ie if the column value is one among the desired column values, how should I use a Filter here? Like in my code posted above I am scanning all the rows and if a column value is among the array of integers defined, I get the row and do processing on it. How can I achieve the same functionality using Fliters

Comment: Not a single comment other than mine? strange

Comment: Can you answer following then can solve proble..
What is the detailed exception..?
Is your reducer really got callled..? put sysout and watch.. open 50030 and paste details..

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions now but the output table still doesn't contain anything. The stdout shows that reducer ran from 0 to 100 percent. I am running this job on a remote server. And can you please tell how to open that 50030? I tried `curl localhost:50030`. It said cannot connect to host

Comment: No that's JobTracker web interface. http://servername:50030/jobtracker.jsp in your browser

Comment: @Rocky111 Thank you for the information. Although before trying out it, I figured the boolean was always getting evaluated to false and so the mapper didn't emit any key,value pair. But when I evaluated the same expression using `if(siteId.equals(siteId1) || siteId.equals(siteId2) || ... 34 site Ids)` , i got the output in the hbase table. But still I am not sure why the boolean didn't work